# MongoDB grouping&sorting

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

the data I'm working with looks like this:

[image]

so I have a root objects with array of elements ('data') which of each one contains field 'eprid'.

The grouping I need to achieve is based on this ('$data.eprid') field alongside with '$$ROOT.createdOn' date --and this would be the most recent date of all the equal 'eprid' values.

In other words, I need to create tuples of unique 'eprid' and 'date' where date is the most recent one of all the equal 'eprid' values from all the documents.

```
[
   {
       "eprid": <uniq.value>,
       "createdOn": <mostRecentDate>
   },
   ...
]
```

The closest I got is

```
db.domains.aggregate( [ 
{ $group : { 
   _id : { "$$ROOT.createdOn" },
    eprid: { $addToSet: "$data.eprid" }
    } } 
] )
```

but that's not even close.

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: [Posting images of code is really discouraging here on SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Consider updating your question to include the actual code for prospective answerers to test with.

Comment: it's not a code it's data structure. 
you can find the code I have posted in code tag.